# How to export a Django-Html web page as an xml file

Tags: html, django, xml

I need to export (basically a download button) an html page with django syntax in XML format. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation about [how to return csv data  generated using the templating system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/outputting-csv/)

You'd generate a suitable file.xml template and render that with the appropriate context. You'd specify that it's XML not HTML in the response object.

This is abbreviated and hacked from the above. I'm unfamiliar with returning XML so this may not be exactly right.

```
def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(
        content_type='text/xml'
        headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="somefilename.xml"'},
    )

    # generate xml_data
    ...

    t = loader.get_template('my_template_name.xml')
    c = {'data': xml_data}
    response.write(t.render(c))
    return response
```